# How to create a view that joins two or more tables to meet the requirements?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of tables given to me and a specific business requirement that needs to be solved by creating a View in SQL. I am having trouble with understanding joins and stuff etc. I have made an attempt, but I think I am completely wrong and need some help.

The tables are as follows:

```
tblClients (
  ClientID, 
  ClientName, 
  ClientAddress, 
  ClientCity, 
  ClientProvince, 
  ClientPostalCode, 
  ClientPhone, 
  ClientEmail
)

tblVehicle (
  VehicleID, 
  VehicleMake, 
  VehicleModel, 
  VehicleYear, 
  ClientID
)

tblEmployees (
  EmployeeID, 
  EmployeeFirstName, 
  EmployeeLastName, 
  EmployeeAddress, 
  EmployeeCity, 
  EmployeeProvince, 
  EmployeePostalCode, 
  EmployeePhone, 
  EmployeeEmail
)

tblWorkOrders (
  OrderID, 
  VehicleID, 
  EmployeeID, 
  WorkDescription, 
  PartsCost, 
  LabourCost, 
  IssueDate, 
  CompletionDate
)
```

---

and the Requirement is this:

A web application is being considered that will allow customers with accounts – using their email address as a login – to view their invoice / work order history with the garage.
Using SQL, create a view that will allow a customer to see work done on each of their cars, including the work description, costs and dates but not which employee completed the work.

---

WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:

```
CREATE VIEW WORK_HISTORY AS
SELECT TBLWORKORDERS.WORKDESCRIPTION,                    
       TBLWORKORDERS.PARTSCOST, TBLWORKORDERS.LABOURCOST,                         
       TBLWORKORDERS.ISSUEDATE,TBLWORKORDERS.COMPLETIONDATE
       TBLVEHICLES.VEHICLEMAKE, TBLVEHICLES.VEHICLEMODEL, 
       TBLVEHICLES.VEHICLEYEAR
  FROM TBLWORKORDERS 
  INNER JOIN TBLVEHICLE
  ON TBLWORKORDERS.VEHICLEID = TBLVEHICLE.VEHICLEID
```

I don't think its too complicated, but I am new to SQL, so all your help and criticism will be appreciated. If you need anything else please let me know and I will edit as necessary. Thank you!

UPDATE: I think it's an inner join.

Comment: This totally looks like homework to me. But you will also need to include the `tblClients` and `INNER JOIN` on the `tblVehicle` on the `ClientID`.

Comment: It is homework. Stackiverflow asked me if it was homework and I said yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below how you would JOIN your tables together in order to link from your Client Table to the Work Orders the client would want to see for their vehicles.

```
/* First Requirement: Filter aka WHERE Clause 
 | The requirement states the Client logs in using their email address.
*/
SELECT *
FROM tblClients c
WHERE c.ClientEmail = 'email@fakeEmail.com'
;

/* Let's expand on this now that we have found the Client by email
 | NEXT Requirement is to find the Invoice/Work Order.
 |   Ask yourself: How do I get from the Clients table to the Work Order Table?
 | I see that the Work Order Table does NOT contain a ClientID.
 |   I see however that it DOES contain a VehicleID and the Vechicle Table has a ClientID.
 | Perfect... I can now get from the Client table to the Work Order table using the Vehicle Table.
*/

SELECT c.ClientName, c.ClientEmail
  , v.VehicleModel
  , wo.WorkDescription, wo.PartsCost, wo.IssueDate, wo.CompletionDate
FROM tblClients c
  /* Tie Clients to their vehicle */
  JOIN tblVehicle v ON v.ClientID = c.ClientID
  /* Now Tie the Vehicle to the Work Orders */
  JOIN tblWorkOrders wo ON wo.VehicleID = v.VehicleID
WHERE /* Add email filter so we can see a specific client.  No filter means see ALL */
  c.ClientEmail = 'email@fakeEmail.com'
;
```

As for creating the View... in this case you would NOT include a WHERE clause but you DO need to include the email address so that you can use it when calling the view.

```
CREATE VIEW WORK_HISTORY AS
SELECT c.ClientName, c.ClientEmail
  , v.VehicleModel
  , wo.WorkDescription, wo.PartsCost, wo.IssueDate, wo.CompletionDate
FROM tblClients c
  /* Tie Clients to their vehicle */
  JOIN tblVehicle v ON v.ClientID = c.ClientID
  /* Now Tie the Vehicle to the Work Orders */
  JOIN tblWorkOrders wo ON wo.VehicleID = v.VehicleID
;
```